# Inspect limit parameter values for SQLServer2008Dialect

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have an hibernate query with paging. I want to see parameter values related to the paging. I use SQLServer2008Dialect so my query looks like:

```
WITH query AS (/* criteria query */ select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
order by
    this_.event_id desc)
...
...
) SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        query 
    WHERE
        __hibernate_row_nr__ BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

I set
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
hibernate.use_sql_comments = true
in hibernate config used by my application.

I enabled also logging query parameters in log4j by setting
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder to TRACE level.

This works fine for fine for all other parameters but I can't see parameter values related to the row number limit. Is there any way to inspect which are the current limit parameter values?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've always used that configuration with hibernate, but recently I've switched to use BoneCP which allows to me log the exact query being executed to avoid having the same problem you are facing.

If you can use BoneCP, you could configure your data source to enable logging statements, and set a log4j logger for `com.jolbox.bonecp` to `debug`, and you are set.